# Rails: CouchSurfing-Like Database Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, data-structures

So my idea is to have an user A requesting any number of arrangements (any service) from another user B. Both user A and B can leave feedbacks to each user B and A (only one per user and service). **Just like CouchSurfing**

I had some thoughts about the setup on the database and ruby on rails, but would be glad if you would have a quick look on it, since I'm still a beginner seeking for knowledge.

**Lets have a sample scenario:**

But first a quick note: It's important that every user has the ability to become an acceptor or requestor.

User A requests this service off another user B (in this case user A becomes the `Requestor` and user B becomes the `Acceptor`, who needs to accept the request of user A). Once user B accepted the request, an `Arragement` is built having its primary key made of the ids of user A and B. Inside this Arrangement Table are several informations related to the arrangement. Once the arrangement took place, both user A and B are allowed to give `feedback` to the other user (**but only one!**)

*This is why I have set up seperate tables for the Acceptor, Requestor and Arrangement. I want to control how many feedbacks a user can give database-wise.*

Now each user has (for sure) a user-show-page where all of his received feedbacks are shown. Means: Every user has N feedbacks (or messages, if you see it database-wise). And that is why I extracted a `Message-Table` out of the `Feedback-Table`

**In short:** It should be very similar to `CouchSurfing`. E.G. the stay at ones home is an arrangement and both the host and guest can leave **one** feedback to oneanother.

What are your thoughts on this setup? Is it good/bad? How can I make it better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds reasonable, but your design limits A and B to having only one Arrangement with A as Requestor and B as Acceptor.

Generate an int id for the Arrangement to use as PK (and as the FK in Feedbacks) and you're there.

Comment: Thanks for your support :P But wouldn't your described issue still work, because I'm passing the acceptors' and requestors' ID to the arrangement? As User A can become an acceptor as many times as he wants to. With this he is only limited to one arrangement by time with user B for the SAME arrangement. Means: User A and B can't "meet up" multiple times in the same arrangement.

Comment: Another one: I just noticed its nonsense pulling Feedbacks and FeedbackMessages apart. :P

Comment: I#m not sure. Your diagram shows, and you say, "its primary key made of the ids of user A and B". If A + B is a PK its unique. Still if you;re aware of this and don't actually do that, then fine.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. I should've said the primary key is made of the ids of the request and acceptance :-) Thanks mate!